# jQuery/JavaScript issues in Safari PC/Mac

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I am almost finished a contract right now, and it appears at the last minute that most of my javascript/jQuery isnt working in Safari on either PC or Mac.

The whole site is designed with progressive enhancement and unobtrusive javascript to turn ?p= links into # hash links, fade pages in and out, and have smooth rollovers - all of which have stopped working for ONLY Safari.

I have read that Safari may be unable to handle large .js files, but my jquery page is under 10k, and I am using a compressed jquery library at about 55k.

Here is what I have now, works in the latest versions of IE, FF, and Chrome - [test.cultureconquest.com](http://test.cultureconquest.com)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many errors are exposed when I run a [jslint](http://jslint.com/) of the main body of your code. Lots of little things, like missing semicolons. Other things, like naming a variable "class", which is a reserved word in JavaScript could be a problem.

You have some logic that can be handled better using real jQuery idioms. For example you do:

```
var class = $(this).attr("class");
class = class.substr(5);

var ext
if ( class == "ccm" ) {
    ext = "cultureconquest.com";
}
if ( class == "gmail" ) {
    ext = "gmail.com";
}
```

jQuery has a method to test whether an element contains a class, [`hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)

```
var ext;
if ($(this).hasClass("ccm")) {
    ext = "cultureconquest.com";
}
if ($(this).hasClass("gmail")) {
    ext = "gmail.com";
}
```

I also notice you're using `livequery()` extension to jQuery. An equivalent method, `live()` was added in jQuery 1.3. See [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) for details.

Those are a few things to look at. If you can get your code to pass a jslint test, I bet you'll be a lot of the way there to getting it working in Safari.

Comment: this fixed it, thanks!

also, I dont think live() covers all functions, such as anchors loaded after the DOM is ready.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem I see is that you are throwing a Parse error because of using the variable name `class` in your two `.MAIL` `.livequery` statements. Just change that variable name (it appears 10 times in those two functions) like this:

```
// SAFE EMAIL //
$(".MAIL").livequery( function() {
    var email = $(this).attr("id");
    var className = $(this).attr("class");
    className = className.substr(5);

    var ext
    if ( className == "ccm" ) {
        ext = "cultureconquest.com";
    }
    if ( className == "gmail" ) {
        ext = "gmail.com";
    }

    document.getElementById(email).innerHTML = email+"&#64;"+ext;
    $(this).attr("title","");
});

$(".MAIL").livequery("click", function() {
    var className = $(this).attr("class");
    className = className.substr(5);

    var ext
    if ( className == "ccm" ) {
        ext = "cultureconquest.com";
    }
    if ( className == "gmail" ) {
        ext = "gmail.com";
    }
    var email = $(this).attr("id")+"@"+ext;
    var mailto = "mailto:"+email;
    window.location = mailto;
});
```